# Filling in Mask Fields __.__.__.___.__ with PHP Unit selenium webdriver

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

Using the PHPUnit Selenium from Sebastian Bergmann( Facebook WebDriver )

Current code to select and fill in the *user_insz* field
With

```
$search7a = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('user_insz'));
$search7a->click();

$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('98121252182');
```

This is the only field that isn't getting filled in in my test. The only difference between this and all other fields is that this one has a mask :

```
__.__.__.___.__
```

so max: 99.99.99.999.99

HTML of the field:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm"><input type="text" id="user_insz" name="user[insz]" data-inputmask="'mask': '99.99.99.999.99'" class="form-control input-sm"><span class="input-group-addon"><strong><p data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Unieke waarde">U</p></strong></span></div>
```

How can I make it fill this in?

**EDIT:** 
Whenever I just copy paste ' 98121252182 ' in it. It works fine. ( Manually )

[image: Field]

This is how the field looks like. Whenever you hover it, it will show the mask.

**EDIT2:**

```
$var = "98121252182";
for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($var); $i++)
{$character = \substr($var, $i,1);
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($character);
}
```

Using this doesn't work either, it tries to enter the numbers 1 by 1 in the field. But it has the same result as the previous options. It just hops to the end of the field (over the mask).

**EDIT3:**

I have found an example online here(but this already shows the mask, not only when you hover over it so not sure if this matters but it has the same effect.):
[Example: Angewatt masked input](http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/masked_input.php)

It's the SSN field: `...-..-....` it works somewhat the same. Whenever you fill something in with selenium it hops towards the end.

```
$this->webDriver->get('http://www.angelwatt.com/coding/masked_input.php');
sleep(3);          
$this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@id="ex-3"]'))->click();
$this->webDriver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys('481878483');
```

Any workaround is welcome

Comment: What's the html code of the field?

Comment: In the code you posted, `$insz` is not a string and you're sending a different value `$this->insz` - either one of those issues could prevent the correct string from being sent. That's a typo, right?

Comment: I dont know how your __.__.__ fields behave, if you could use *TAB* to change the cursor, then you could split your $insz to an Array -> Type  98 -> Tab -> Type 12 -> Tab -> etc ...

Comment: added html to post. @Nguyen , tabs won't work. if you click on the field and start entering the numbers it hops to the end of the field after the last _

Comment: try sending some DELETE keys before the actual numbers. I once had a similar issue and I solved it this way.

Comment: @gontrollez Thx for the suggestion, Just tried it but didn't work for me.